# Google cloud endpoints add nginx

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

Can i run Nginx plugins in cloud endpoints/ESP?

I think about lua plugin to run custom functions. Is there a solution to do that?

My starting point is a custom Nginx config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deploying ESP directly using Google Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, or Kubernetes, you have access to nginx. You can add other nginx plugins if needed. However, this is an unsupported use case and Cloud Endpoints does not guarantee that the plugins will be compatible, nor does it provide support for this usage.